# React: page not redirected and getting Warning: State updates from the useState() and useReducer() Hooks don't support the second callback argument

Tags: reactjs

**Goal:** 
I want to get stripe charged, an email sent, cart in local storage cleared, then a message is shown to the user that is successful, then redirect to home page. Everything works fine, until the last step. After the success message is shown, it's not redirected.

**Error:**

> Warning: State updates from the useState() and useReducer() Hooks
>   don't support the second callback argument. To execute a side effect
>   after rendering, declare it in the component body with useEffect().

**System:**

- Node.js version: 12.13.0
- NPM version: 6.12.0
- Strapi version: 3.0.0-beta.17.4
- Database: MongoDB atlas cloud
- Operating system: LinuxMint 19.2 Cinnamon
- Front-end : React 16.11.0
- strapi-provider-email-sendgrid": "^3.0.0-beta.17.5"

**Code:**

```
const [cartItems,setCartItems] = useState([])

    useEffect(()=> {
        const items = getCart()
        setCartItems(items)
    }, [])


    const showToast = (toastMsg, redirect = false) => {
        setFormData({...formData, toast: true, toastMsg})
        setTimeout(() => setFormData({...formData, toast: false, toastMsg:''},
        // if true passed to 'redirect' argument, redirect home
         ()=> redirect && props.history.push('/')), 
        5000)
    }

const handleSubmitOrder = async () => {
        const amount = calculateAmount(cartItems)
        setFormData({...formData, orderProcessing: true})

        let token
        try {
            //create stripe token
            //create order with strapi (request to backend)
            //set orderProcessing to false set modal to false
            //clear user cart 
            //show success toast 
            let jwtToken = getToken()
            // console.log(jwtToken)
            const response = await props.stripe.createToken()
            token = response.token.id
            // console.log(token)
            const headers = {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer '+ jwtToken
              }
            await axios
            .post(`${apiUrl}/orders`, {
                amount, 
                productItems: cartItems,
                city,
                zipcode, 
                address,
                token
            }, {headers})
            await axios
            .post(`${apiUrl}/email`, {
                    to: confirmEmail,
                    from: 'hi@anniesveganbakery.com',
                    subject: `Order Confirmation from Annie's Vegan Bakery`,
                    text: 'Your order has been processed.',
                    html: '<h1>Expect your order to arrive in 2-3 shipping days.</h1>'
                }
            ,{headers})
            setFormData({...formData, orderProcessing: false, modal: false})
            clearCart()
            showToast('Your order has been successfully submitted', true)
        } catch (error) {
            //set order processing to false, modal to false
            //show error message in toast
            setFormData({...formData, orderProcessing: false, modal: false})
            showToast(error.message)
        }
    }
```

**Question:** what is causing this problem and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by writing it like this

```
 const showToast = (toastMsg, redirect = false) => {
        setFormData({...formData, toast: true, toastMsg})
        setTimeout(() => setFormData({...formData, toast: false, toastMsg:''}), 5000)
        // if true passed to 'redirect' argument, redirect home
        setTimeout(() => redirect &&  props.history.push('/'), 6000)
    }
```

I am not sure it's the best way but no errors now and everything works well.